# Is it possible to sanitize a shared (HAL) library that is loaded by another system library?

Tags: android, address-sanitizer

We're developing Android HAL libraries, and our shared libraries are loaded by a Android system service library or other HAL libraries. Now that we're trying to sanitize our libraries, we're running into some issues that looks very much like false positives (`wild pointer`/`free without malloc`). For instance, ASan aborts on errors in one of the libraries (`lib_a.so`) that I know for a fact is tested in sanitized unit tests (on the same devices), so this particular library should be free and clear from any memory issues (I have confirmed that the code that ASan complains about is covered by the unit tests).

Yet it aborts immediately after it is loaded, it seems. This particular library is built outside of AOSP using a custom toolchain, since we target multiple operating systems. It aborts with the same message regardless if this library is sanitized or not, which is what leads me to believe that it is a false positive of sorts, possibly due to unintended use case or plain old lack of understanding of how all this should be set up.

Here is how the libraries are loaded: `System service lib` -> `our HAL:s` -> `lib_a.so`

I came across this while reading the [documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/asan#sanitizing_shared_libraries_with_asan):

> Due to the way ASan works, a library built with ASan can only be used by an executable that's built with ASan.

I am not sure how to interpret this. Does it mean that we **have** to use an executable to sanitize our shared library, or does it simply mean that if we happen to have both an executable and a shared library, the executable must be sanitized as well? The latter is of course not possible in our scenario, since our library is loaded by a Android system library, and not directly by an executable per se.

Is there a way of sanitizing a shared library where said library is loaded by an unsanitized native system library, and not by a sanitized executable?

Perhaps we need a fully sanitized Android build for this particular use case, since I can imagine that the system executable that ultimately loads the system services should be sanitized as well? This would certainly make sense given the documentation snippet above, but is it possible to get around that? If not, I suppose I just answered my own question, and are just looking for clarification on how this works.